# Getting an undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.responseText') when making API request

Tags: javascript

As a bit of a background, I have recently picked up JavaScript and am currently trying to figure out API requests, so this may seem extremely simple to someone - but I can't seem to wrap my head around the reason for this error.

Aim of the request is to provide an API endpoint and the required parameters, ideally when clicking a button on the HTML page, it will make a request and display the data in table form.

Below is the code which works perfectly fine without the button option (app.js):

````
function success() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); //parse the string to JSON
    table1.innerHTML = data.id;
    table2.innerHTML = data.accountId;
    table3.innerHTML = data.name;
    table4.innerHTML = data.profileIconId
    table5.innerHTML = data.puuid;
    table6.innerHTML = data.revisionDate;
    table7.innerHTML = data.summonerLevel;
    console.log(data);
}

// function to handle error
function error(err) {
    console.log('Request Failed', err); //error details will be in the "err" object
}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //invoke a new instance of the XMLHttpRequest
xhr.onload = success; // call success function if request is successful
xhr.onerror = error;  // call error function if request failed
xhr.open('GET', `https://eun1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/summonerName?api_key=${apiKey}`); // open a GET request
xhr.send(); // send the request to the server.```
````

The code above loads the required data as soon as the page is refreshed.
However, when trying to trigger the function to be called only when the user clicks a button, which contains `onclick="getData()"` as follows:

````
function success() {
    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); //parse the string to JSON
    table1.innerHTML = data.id;
    table2.innerHTML = data.accountId;
    table3.innerHTML = data.name;
    table4.innerHTML = data.profileIconId
    table5.innerHTML = data.puuid;
    table6.innerHTML = data.revisionDate;
    table7.innerHTML = data.summonerLevel;
    console.log(data);
}

// function to handle error
function error(err) {
    console.log('Request Failed', err); //error details will be in the "err" object
}

function getData(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); //invoke a new instance of the XMLHttpRequest
    xhr.onload = success; // call success function if request is successful
    xhr.onerror = error;  // call error function if request failed
    xhr.open('GET', `https://eun1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/summonerName?api_key=${apiKey}`); // open a GET request
    xhr.send(); // send the request to the server.
}```
````

It fails with **TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.responseText')**

I know I'm missing something very obvious here, but if anyone can explain why this doesn't work as I'm expecting in my head, that would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Could you paste the html which you used?

Comment: @JackYu Sure, sorry missed that part in the code above. 
`<div>
                <input type="button" class="u-full-width" id="btn" value="Search User" onclick="getData()"/>
            </div>`

Now one thing to note is that Im not passing the user input into the link just yet, wanted to get the basic part right first - so hard coding the API required parameters.

Comment: it's weird. I tried your code, but it's fine for me which click button to trigger the `getData()`. I thought it's a `this` issue, but it looks not. Did you use other convertor in your app.js? How do you include app.js in html? Use `<script src=""></script>` ?

Comment: Could you help me try to `console.log(this)` before you use `JSON.parse` when you use button click to trigger `getData()`?

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the `success()` function to

```
function success(server) {
var data = JSON.parse(server.responseText); //parse the string to JSON
table1.innerHTML = data.id;
table2.innerHTML = data.accountId;
table3.innerHTML = data.name;
table4.innerHTML = data.profileIconId
table5.innerHTML = data.puuid;
table6.innerHTML = data.revisionDate;
table7.innerHTML = data.summonerLevel;
console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that @Julius. Added the server param in and the data is being returned as expected now. 
Would you mind explaining the reason for passing the server param in? Just want to understand the need for that and why I have missed It out, thanks again.

Comment: Your code and mine should work the same. It may depend on your browser type or version. What could be the case with your browser is that without the `getData()` function, the `success` callback and the `xhr.onload` share the same `constructor`  which is still the argument of the `success` callback making it possible to use `this` whereas with the `getData()`, the `constructor` is shared between `getData()` and `success` callback whose initializations do not include responseText So the `constructor` of `xhr.onload` is passed as an argument only to `success` callback